# Extracting a resource ID from a URL - Working backwards

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following:

```
https://test.blob.core.windows.net/container-2/3a54d521-bf6f-4ffd-b19f-8656332a6ed?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=m88kVRUpsqGYKI0ChMTfjWt%2BW1bliQY1P4BjsW7YPs%3D&se=9999-12-31T23%3A59%3A59Z&sp=r
```

I would like to extract `3a54d521-bf6f-4ffd-b19f-8656332a6ed` from the string.  I believe the rules will be -

- Anything after and including `?` can be discarded
- Then, working left, take whatever comes after the first `/`

How can this be achieved using RegEx (or another approach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Uri` like this code

```C#
string url = @"https://test.blob.core.windows.net/container-2/3a54d521-bf6f-4ffd-b19f-8656332a6ed?sv=2016-05-31&sr=c&sig=m88kVRUpsqGYKI0ChMTfjWt%2BW1bliQY1P4BjsW7YPs%3D&se=9999-12-31T23%3A59%3A59Z&sp=r";
var uri = new Uri(url);
Console.WriteLine(uri.Segments[2]);
Console.ReadLine();
```